# What is code for stair treads and risers in Georgia

Tags: code-compliance, stairs

What are the codes in Georgia (the US state, not the country) regarding stair treads and risers in a townhome or condo? My daughter is looking to purchase and the stairs seem too steep. The condo was built in 2005.

I'm asking because my daughters house that she is signing a contract on today, the stairs are now tiled. It seems really steep and my shoe size is an eight. Putting my foot down on the "step" is 9".

I'm having a problem coming up with the correct building code that it must be. The condo was built in 2004. One realtor said to me the stairs are not up to code, but another has said differently. The stairs will be carpeted, but obviously will need to be fixed and I need to know what they should be before signing papers today. The seller does not want to fix anything, but I know you can't sell a house if doesn't comply with Georgia codes aren't in order.

Comment: I thought the max rise was 7 or maybe 8" with a tread of 10". This always feels steep to me because of size 15 boots. What is the rise and tread width you are asking about?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your post if you have further information to add to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Georgia revises its building code frequently.  I didn't find a revision for 2005, but the 2006 edition was OCR scanned and published [here](https://archive.org/stream/gov.ga.building/ga_building_djvu.txt).

In section 1009.3, there is this:

> **1009.3 Stair treads and risers** Stair riser heights shall be 7 
>   inches (178 mm) maximum and 4 inches (102 mm) minimum. 
>   Stair tread depths shall be 11 inches (279 mm) minimum. The 
>   riser height shall be measured vertically between the leading 
>   edges of adjacent treads. The tread depth shall be measured 
>   horizontally between the vertical planes of the foremost projection of adjacent treads and at a right angle to the tread's leading 
>   edge. Winder treads shall have a minimum tread depth of 11 
>   inches (279 mm) measured at a right angle to the tread's leading edge at a point 12 inches (305 mm) from the side where the 
>   treads are narrower and a minimum tread depth of 10 inches 
>   (254 mm).

(I have cleaned up OCR defects.)